# Oracle Cursor has_value Used But Doesn't Exist

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I have this giant query which uses some text in it which look like variables but I have no idea what they are and I really can't figure it out. They aren't global or defined anywhere else in the oracle package. In particular below the variable(or whatever it is) called "has_value" is so confusing because it's used in multiple cases for queries across a LOT of tables.

```
PROCEDURE assemble_default_where(
    i_search_id    IN     search_table.search_id%TYPE,
    o_where_clause OUT    VARCHAR2,
    o_from_clause  OUT    VARCHAR2,
    o_error_number OUT    error_message.error_number%TYPE) IS
    l_base VARCHAR2(30) := 'd';

    CURSOR c_where_clause IS
      SELECT   DECODE
                 (sl.parameter_name,
                  'track Location', join_operator || ' ' || open_brackets || ' ' || not_operator || ' EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM track_locations loc WHERE ' || l_base
                   || '.plan_number = loc.plan_number AND ' || l_base || '.order_id = loc.order_id AND loc.t_id = NVL('''
                   || track_location_rsect_id(has_value) || ''', loc.t_id) AND loc.tstatus = NVL(''' || track_tstatus_id(has_value)

FROM     search_lines sl
      WHERE    search_id = i_search_id
      ORDER BY line_no;
```

I have left out a bit of the query because it's not relevant to my question.

I want to know where join_operator, has_value and open_brackets come from and what they are???

Answer (score 0):

There are several options:

1. Variable - defined in outer block.
2. Variable - defined in package body.
3. Variable - defined in package specification.
4. Column - the same column names could be in many tables.
5. Function - in the invoker's or definer's schema.
6. Library - in the invoker's or definer's schema.
7. Operator - in the invoker's or definer's schema.
8. Synonym - to a function, operator, or library.

In practice you probably would have already noticed if it was #1, #2, #3, or #4.  And #6 and #7 are very rare.  I would guess it is a function or a synonym to a function.

To rule out variables, search through the code either in your IDE or with this SQL:

```
select * from dba_source where lower(text) like '%join_operator%';
```

To rule out objects, search though all the objects with this SQL:

```
select * from dba_objects where object_name = 'JOIN_OPERATOR';
```

---

**UPDATE**

[PL/SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_plscope.htm#ADFNS022) and `DBA_DEPENDENCIES` can also help identify objects.

**Sample schema**

```
alter session set plscope_settings = 'IDENTIFIERS:ALL';

create table search_lines(
    search_id number, line_no number, parameter_name varchar2(100));

create or replace function join_operator_function return varchar2 is
begin
    return 'asdf';
end;
/

create synonym join_operator for join_operator_function;

create or replace PROCEDURE assemble_default_where
is
    CURSOR c_where_clause IS
    SELECT DECODE(sl.parameter_name, 'track Location', join_operator)
    FROM     search_lines sl
    ORDER BY line_no;
begin
    null;
end;
/
```

**PL/SCOPE example**

```
WITH v AS (
  SELECT    Line,
            Col,
            INITCAP(NAME) Name,
            LOWER(TYPE)   Type,
            LOWER(USAGE)  Usage,
            USAGE_ID,
            USAGE_CONTEXT_ID
    FROM USER_IDENTIFIERS
      WHERE Object_Name = 'ASSEMBLE_DEFAULT_WHERE'
        AND Object_Type = 'PROCEDURE'
)
SELECT RPAD(LPAD(' ', 2*(Level-1)) ||
                 Name, 30, '.')||' '||
                 RPAD(Type, 30)||
                 RPAD(Usage, 30)
                 IDENTIFIER_USAGE_CONTEXTS
  FROM v
  START WITH USAGE_CONTEXT_ID = 0
  CONNECT BY PRIOR USAGE_ID = USAGE_CONTEXT_ID
  ORDER SIBLINGS BY Line, Col
/

Assemble_Default_Where........ procedure                     declaration
  Assemble_Default_Where...... procedure                     definition
    C_Where_Clause............ cursor                        declaration
      Join_Operator_Function.. function                      call
```

**DBA_DEPENDENCIES example**

```
select referenced_owner, referenced_name, referenced_type
from dba_dependencies
where owner = user
    and name = 'ASSEMBLE_DEFAULT_WHERE';       

REFERENCED_OWNER    REFERENCED_NAME                 REFERENCED_TYPE
----------------    ---------------                 ---------------
SYS                 STANDARD                        PACKAGE
SYS                 SYS_STUB_FOR_PURITY_ANALYSIS    PACKAGE
JHELLER_DBA         JOIN_OPERATOR                   SYNONYM
JHELLER_DBA         JOIN_OPERATOR_FUNCTION          FUNCTION
JHELLER_DBA         SEARCH_LINES                    TABLE
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I ruled out the objects with your query as there were no results. I also ruled out variables by searching through my code and running your query.

Comment: I also just now checked the dba_synonyms and found nothing in there like join_operator or has_value

Comment: One other thing to check - is the procedure valid?